# codeigniter template parsing with parameters

Tags: php, content-management-system

I am working on a php CMS project based on "codeigniter" php framework. This is a general question though. I want one of my "view" to include some dynamic content off the database containing some php code. One option is inserting the php code in the database and then using eval() to run it, as only an admin should be able to edit the database (i know it is definitely not secure) other option is to use a template parser, since iam not going for the first one for obvious reasons (unless someone really convinces me to), i would like to know a few things

1- Template parsing class in codeigniter (or any other framework) is designed to replace hardcoded template data 
say {title} will be replaced by .< title >. blah .< / title >. (ignore the dots)

so is it possible to pass parameters along with it say

{f}blah,blah1{/f} => .< form method="blah" action="blah1" >. or 
{bu}blah{/bu} => base_url(blah);

2- Should/can this be done without using the template class at all, as template parsing will require more cpu cycles than a native php code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps you:
View1:

```
<head>
<title><?=$title?></title>
<head>
```

view2:

```
<?=$head?>
<body>
Hello
</body
```

Controller:

```
$subdata['title'] = 'My title';
$data['hello'] = $this->load->view('view1',$subdata,TRUE);
$this->load->view('view2',$data);
```

Comment: ummmm, thanks but i think this is not what i was asking for, in this case the files view1 and view2 should exist physically i believe, but how to create these files dynamically (maybe off the database)